# egrep how to search for words with conditions both at start of line and in middle of line?

Tags: regex, grep

Say I have a text file filled with words named example.txt and i want to look for the word 'cat' but i get the word 'scat' in my search results that i do not want in my output. so i would do

`egrep [^s]cat example.txt`

to get all occurances of 'cat' without 'scat'. However, when i perform this all of the occurrences of cat that were at the beginning of the line dissappear. I think it has to do with the use of the caret but I'm not sure of right command to produce the output i am looking for

Comment: This might help: `grep '\bcat\b' example.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Simply chain greps:

```
egrep cat example.txt | egrep -v scat
```

Alternatively, check for start of line OR not `s`:

```
egrep '(^|[^s])cat' example.txt
```

Comment: Or as specify word boundaries `'\bcat\b'` as @Cyrus pointed out